# How to pass export variable with two find command output in shell script

Tags: shell-script

I have a find command as part of a script and exporting the values into the variable like below

```
export value1="'find /app/new1 -name '*service.sh*'"
```

After testing I realized, on few hosts, the directory is diff like below

```
/sbclocal/app/new1
```

How do i check and pass both into same value?

as I finding this script and executing with stop or start later.

Comment: You've got three single-quote marks in that first `export`. Is that really correct?

Comment: It's also not at all clear what you're asking. Please show what you want to do with examples. (What does "_the directory is diff_" mean? What do you mean by "_How do I check and pass both into same value_" - do you just want `find /path1 /path2 -actions...`?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand the question correct, there are few ways to achieve a desired state.

1. `find` supports multiple paths specified. So it's not a big deal to put it this way:

   ```
   export value1="$(find /app/new1 /sbclocal/app/new1 -name '*service.sh*')"
   ```

   This will produce an error message, if one of dirs is missing, but (depending on your way) it might not affect your script in general.
2. Pass two commands to value:

   ```
   export value1="$(find /app/new1 -name '*service.sh*' && find /sbclocal/app/new1 -name '*service.sh*')"
   ```

   This option provides an answer which is closer to your question (passing two commands to the same variable), but doesn't look like a better solution.
3. Way with checks:

   ```
   export value1="$(for dir in /app/new1 /sbclocal/app/new1; do [ -d $dir ] && find $dir -name '*service.sh*'; done)"
   ```