# Append two find command outputs to single variable but not to a file

Tags: bash, shell-script

my use case is to output of two find commands to a single variable ( not to a file) , few of the things I tried and learnt it won't work are

The actual `find` commands are :

```
find /opt/apps -xdev -type f -name '*vunn*-2*jar'
find /opt/apps -xdev -type f -name '*robj-2*jar'
```

option1: only second output is getting saved.

```
temp_jars=$(find /opt/apps -xdev -type f -name '*vunn*-2*jar')
temp_jars=$(find /opt/apps -xdev -type f -name '*robj*-2*jar')
```

option2: based on the [reference](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/523149/how-to-pass-export-variable-with-two-find-command-output-in-shell-script) , tried below but only 1st command is getting executed.

```
export temp_jars="$(find /opt/apps -xdev -type f -name '*vunn*-2*jar' && find /opt/apps -xdev -type f -name '*robj-2*jar')"
```

your help is appreciated.

Comment: What do you want to do with that variable? Might be better to use an array.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are various ways of doing this. In your case, the simplest approach would be to combine the `find` commands and avoid the entire issue:

```
temp_jars=$(find /opt/apps -xdev -type f \( -name '*vunn*-2*jar' -o -name '*robj-2*jar' \)
```

For other cases, where you really need multiple commands, you can run them separately and *append* the output to the variable instead of overwriting (which is what you do when you run `foo=bar` and then `foo=baz`, only the last action is kept since that has overwritten the first):

```
$ var=$(echo foo)
$ var="$var $(echo bar)"
$ echo "$var"
foo bar
```

Or, to do it in one step:

```
$ var="$(echo foo; echo bar)"
$ echo "$var"
foo
bar
```

The approach you used, with the `&&` instead of `;` means the second command will only be executed if the first was successful, so if your first `find` failed for whatever reason (note that `find` doesn't fail if it finds no results, only of an error occurs, for example if you tell it to search in a directory that does not exist), the second would not run. In your case, I don't see any reason why the `&&` would have failed, are you sure it didn't work?

Answer (score 2):

To store several values, use an array, not a scalar variable:

```
readarray -td '' temp_jars < <(
  find /opt/apps -xdev -type f -name '*vunn*-2*jar' -print0
  find /opt/apps -xdev -type f -name '*robj*-2*jar' -print0
)
```

(the `-d` option, which is used here to specify NUL as the delimiter requires bash 4.4 or newer).

Though here, unless it's important the `vunn` ones be listed before the `robj` ones, as already said by @terdon, you can do it with one `find` command.

Then, to pass the file names to some command as separate arguments, use `"${temp_jars[@]}"`.

For example:

```
printf ' * %s\n' "${temp_jars[@]}"
```

Note that you can't `export` an array variable. Environment variables are scalar only and like bash variables can't contain NUL bytes, so can't reliably hold lists of file paths (which themselves can also be made of any (non-empty) sequence of non-null bytes) unless you use some form of encoding / quoting.

Also note that the exit status of the subshell started by the process substitution (which in this case would be the exit status of the second `find` command) is lost, though with recent versions of `bash` you can obtain it with `wait "$!"; status=$?`.

`readarray` (aka `mapfile` though it has nothing to do with `zsh`'s `mapfile` and doesn't really do a *mapping*) is `bash`-specific. The `zsh` equivalent  here would be:

```
temp_jars=(
  ${(0)"$(
    find /opt/apps -xdev -type f -name '*vunn*-2*jar' -print0
    find /opt/apps -xdev -type f -name '*robj*-2*jar' -print0
  )"}
)
```

Using the `0` parameter expansion flag to do the splitting on NULs. In that case, the exit status is directly available (in `$?` as usual).

To append elements to an array, in both `zsh` and `bash`, you can do:

```
temp_jars+=(more elements)
```

With bash's `readarray` you can use the `-O` option to specify at which index of the array to start storing values.

You can get the last assigned index of an array with:

```
indexes=("${!temp_jars[@]}"); last_index=${indexes[-1]}
```

And then use:

```
readarray -td '' -O "$((last_index + 1))" temp_jars < <(find ... -print0)
```

If the array was initially not sparse (as would be the case after a previous straight `readarray`), that can be simplified to:

```
readarray -td '' -O "${#temp_jars[@]}" temp_jars < <(find ... -print0)
```

Where `${#temp_jars[@]}` is the number of elements in the array (which if the array is not sparse, corresponds to one plus the last assigned index since array indexes start at 0 instead of 1).

In `zsh`, like in most other shells, arrays are not sparse and have their index start at 1; `$#temp_jars` is the number of elements as well as the last assigned index.